# How do you remove the short product description from the product page Magento 2

Tags: magento-2.1, attribute-set

I don't want the short description to show up on my product pages. How do I get rid of it? I am in Magento 2.1.2. I've tried deleting it from the attribute set but it won't let me remove it. Perhaps it is because I already have data in there? Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You remove it in layout xml. Make the file `{theme_dir}/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml` with this contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.overview" remove="true"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

and flush the cache.

Answer (score 0):

```
<referenceContainer name="product.info.overview" remove="true"/>
```