# Remove short product description from Catalog page

Tags: magento2, catalog

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 using php 7.3.15 and my Magneto 2 version is 2.3.3

Some of my short product descriptions seem to be overlaping the price in the Catalog.
I have been searching around Google and my Magento 2 admin panel but I doesn't seem to find if I can disable the short description from the Catalog page so that it doesn't overlap the price.
I stil want the short description on the product page.

Anyone got any ideas?

I've already checked at:

- [How do you remove the short product description from the product page Magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/146331/how-do-you-remove-the-short-product-description-from-the-product-page-magento-2)
- https://www.templatemonster.com/help/magento-how-to-disable-short-description-field-for-products.html
- https://www.shashidharkumar.com/remove-short-description-products-description-page/

[image]

Comment: This is the Product Page or category page?

Answer (score 0):

Go to your Catalog Page or Block and add css

```
<style>
.short_des_class_name{
    display:none
}
</style>
```

**NOTE:** Add this css in catalog page only not in style.css

Answer (score 0):

Go this file and add this code **`catalog_category_view.xml`** :-

```
<referenceBlock name="product.info.overview" remove="true"/>
```

And Second way is Using css :-

```
.your_des_class{
display:none;
}
```

After All changes run below command :-

```
php bin/magento c:c
php bin/magento c:f
```

**`THANKS.`**

Answer (score 0):

Please override your file catalog_category_view.xml in your theme.

From : vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/layout/catalog_category_view.xml

To : app/design/frontend/Vendor/ThemeName/Magento_Catalog/frontend/layout/catalog_category_view.xml

After that add below in your file.

Answer (score 0):

Follow below steps for remove product description from the category page :

1. Override vendor file in to your theme or extension. 
   `vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/list.phtml`
2. Like -
   `app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Catalog/frontend/templates/product/list.phtml`
3. And replace below variable value 
   $showDescription = true; to $showDescription = false;